# r dendrogram - groupLabels not match real labels (package dendextend)

Tags: r, dendrogram, dendextend

Let's do a quick 3-clusters classification on the *iris dataset* with the **FactoMineR** package:

```
library(FactoMineR)
model <- HCPC(iris[,1:4], nb.clust = 3)
summary(model$data.clust$clust)

 1  2  3
50 62 38
```

We see that 50 observations are in cluster 1, 62 in cluster 2 and 38 in cluster 3.

Now, we want to visualize these 3 clusters in a dendrogram, with the package **dendextend** which enables to make pretty ones:

```
library(dendextend)
library(dplyr)
model$call$t$tree %>% 
    as.dendrogram() %>% 
    color_branches(k = 3, groupLabels = unique(model$data.clust$clust)) %>% 
    plot()
```

[image]

The problem is that the **labels on the dendrogram don't meet the true labels** of the classification. The cluster 2 should be the biggest one (62 observations according to the data), but on the dendrogram, we clearly see it is the smallest one.

I tried different thinks but nothing work for now, so if you have any idea of which input give to `groupLabels =`  in order to match the real labels, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking inside `dendextend::color_branches`, we can see that group labels are assigned using the command `g <- dendextend::cutree(dend, k = k, h = h, order_clusters_as_data = FALSE)`.
This fact can be used  for building a map between the cluster labels assigned by `HCPC` and group labels assigned by `dendextend::color_branches`.

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(dendextend)
library(dplyr)
model <- HCPC(iris[,1:4], nb.clust = 3)  

clust.hcpc <- as.numeric(model$data.clust$clust)
clust.cutree <- dendextend:::cutree(model$call$t$tree, k=3, order_clusters_as_data = FALSE)
idx <- order(as.numeric(names(clust.cutree)))
clust.cutree <- clust.cutree[idx]
( tbl <- table(clust.hcpc, clust.cutree) )

###########
          clust.cutree
clust.hcpc  1  2  3
         1 50  0  0
         2  0  0 62
         3  0 36  2
```

This table shows that cluster labels 2 and 3 are matched with group labels 3 and 2, respectively. (Surprisingly, for two sample units this rule is not true.)

The groups levels that need to be passed to `dendextend::color_branches` can be found as follows:

```
( lbls <- apply(tbl,2,which.max) )

##############
1 2 3 
1 3 2
```

Here is the dendrogram:

```
model$call$t$tree %>% 
    color_branches(k=3, groupLabels =lbls) %>% 
    set("labels_cex", .5) %>% 
    plot(horiz=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Marco. Thanks. If you have any suggestions on how to make dendextend better - feel free to send PR.

Comment: Hi Marco, the trick to use `which.max` on the `table` in order to reorder correctly the number is excellent ! Thanks.

Comment: Yep. About the two surprising sample units that not respect the rules, it's because of the option `consol = T` in the HCPC function, that makes some modifications (cluster consolidations with kmeans).

Comment: @S.Demars Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: for those needing the labels to be colored as well I had to do the following (I used res.hcpc rather than model):
`( dend_to_hcpc <- apply(tbl,2,which.max) )`

`( hcpc_to_dend <- apply(tbl, 1, which.max) )`

`dend <- res.hcpc$call$t$tree %>% color_branches(k = res.hcpc$call$t$nb.clust, groupLabels = dend_to_hcpc, col = spectral_colors_array[dend_to_hcpc]) %>%
  set("labels_cex", 0.5) %>% set("branches_lwd", 3.0)`

`labels_colors(dend) <-
 spectral_colors_array[dend_to_hcpc[clust.cutree[match(labels(dend), names(clust.cutree))]]]`